# ¿Es posible crear un exe en python que reciba un parámetro?

Tags: python

tengo un software implementado en visual basic y desde el ejecutable hecho en este quiero llamar al realizado en python y que este reciba 1 parámetro especifico para que una función lo procese y genere un txt y se cierre.

Este es el codigo de ejemplo que utilizaría si llamara desde un ejecutable a otro hecho en Vb6, pero como no tengo idea de como se realizaria en Python lo pongo sólo a modo ilustrativo...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 If Command <> PARAMETRO Then
    ' SALIR DE APLICION PARA METRO INCORRECTO
 Else
    ' PROCESAR PARAMETRO
    ' GENERAR TXT
    ' SALIR
 End If
End Sub
```

espero se me entienda, traté de ser lo más claro posible.

Comment: usando `argparser` se puede

Comment: waooo que rapido obtuve la respuesta. Muchas gracias! creo que esta es la solucion solo con una busqueda en google (ahora sabiendo por domnde empezar) obtuve este enlace  >>>  https://ellibrodepython.com/python-argparse <<<

Comment: Que bueno!, no elaboré una respuesta porque no entendí muy bien tu problema, te recomiendo que edites un poco tu pregunta y pongas un ejemplo en python de lo que quieres (obviamente sin la parte de recibir argumentos)

Comment: Incluso argparse puede ser excesivo. Seguramente te baste con `sys.argv`

Comment: Si disculpa pero crei que no era necesario poner nada de codigo por que la idea es solo usar una funcione que recibe argumentos pero estos vienen como parametros.

Comment: He visto sys.org y creo que tambien me sirve. Me estoy enamorando de python pero lo empece hacer solo unos dias. Y me lance de lleno a tratar de resolver un problema real que tenia en mi soft viejo de vb6 y solucionarlo con python pero a modo de archivo Externo o sea seguir usando mi software que es bastante grande pero una funcion especifica y que consume muchos recursos como estaba reemplazada con una app de Python que es MUCHISIMAaaa más potente y veloz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gracias a @Christian que me oriento en la búsqueda he resuelto lo que buscaba con algo como esto...

```
import argparse
from ast import arg
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Calculadora, suma/resta')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--numero_a', type=int, help='Parametro1')
parser.add_argument('-b','--numero_b', type=int, help='Parametro2')
parser.add_argument('-o','--operacion',type=str,choices=['suma','resta'],default='suma',required=False,help='Operacion')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.operacion =='suma':
    print(args.numero_a + args.numero_b)
elif args.operacion == 'resta':
    print(args.numero_a - args.numero_b)
print('FIN')
```

[fuente](https://ellibrodepython.com/python-argparse)